# View Criteria not returning row when bind value starting with "In "

Tags: criteria, oracle-adf

I am trying to retrieve the records where the customer name is "In CustomerName".

```
CustomerValuePVOImpl  ttvpvo = ddAM.getCustomerValueP1();
ViewCriteria vc = ttvpvo.createViewCriteria();
ViewCriteriaRow vcRow = vc.createViewCriteriaRow();
vcRow.setAttribute("CustomerName", "In CustomerName");
```

I am able to get the records for the value "CustomerName" but not able to retrieve the records for "In CustomerName" even if the database contains the records.